# Landing page, destination page, or destination URL?

Tags: google-analytics

Which is the better dimension to use when we're using UTM-tagged web links on social media posts -- landing page, destination page, or destination URL?

We launched and are promoting a new website on social media, using the URLs of the respective pages we're posting about. I want to create a dashboard on GA that captures pageviews and average time spent, but confused whether we should be using the landing page dimension, destination page, or destination URL. Things we've read online are not clearly applicable.

This should be a subset of the overall pageviews/sessions of the new site.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the landing page dimension. It is the page the user started the session on.